# Reload page based on selected ID from dropdown

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to reload my page based on the selection of a value in a dropdownlist in MVC 3.
My dropdown is defined as such:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ID, new SelectList(Model.SchoolBranches, "ID", "Name", Model.ID), new { id = "Branches", name = "Branches"})
```

My script is defined as such so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#Branches").change(function () {
            var selected;
            selected = $(this).val();
            alert(selected);
            // make a call to the Index action passing in the 'selected' value to reload the whole page
    });
});
</script>
```

My selected ID is working fine as the alert show the correct ID on change. Just can't find any examples that show how to navigate back to the index action and send the new ID. All the samples I have found show partial page or such refresh using ajax. I need the whole page reloaded.

Thanks

**UPDATE**:

Using @Brandon's help, I've tried these approaches

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#Branches").change(function () {
            var selected;
            var url;
            selected = $(this).val();
            url = '@Url.Action("Index", "School")';
            alert(url); //gives /School/Index/55  this is also  my current page in my browser address bar
            url = '@Url.Action("Index", "School", new {id = ""})';
            alert(url); //gives /School
            url = '@Url.Action("Index", "School", new {id = ""})' + '/' + selected;
            alert(url); //gives /School/41 

            // window.location = url;
        });
    });

</script>
```

This is my route in global.asax just so you can see that I don't have any crazy routes going on

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    //routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
}
```

**Update**

This works:

```
url = '@Url.Action("NotIndex", "School", new {id = ""})' + '/' + selected;
```

I get the correct new Url and the action is hit with the selected ID

Comment: do you want the ID in query string in url for reload?

Comment: @Archer the Index action on the controller that originally loaded the page.

Comment: @charlietfl yes I expect the new selected ID to be part of the URL to navigate to the action. The page is sitting on /Controller/Index/55 where 55 is the ID of a selected item from a previous page. On this page I have a dropdown to choose a different ID and need to reload the page.

Comment: @CDSmith, Index is your default action listed in your routes, it would leave out the action name because it wouldn't need it. The request would be routed to Index anyways. Are you actually getting an error using the code or are you just not getting the URL string you want? The redirect should still be functional.

Comment: @Brandon yes getting an error, I get Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request. Page not found.

The page /School/41 does not exist.

Comment: @Brandon I could do a couple dif things I guess.. rename my action.. or use url = '@Url.Action("Index", new {id = ""})' + '/Index/' + selected; But I dislike the latter as I'm being redundant

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just set `window.location`.

```
window.location = '@Url.Action("Index", "Controller", new { id = "" })' + '/' + selected;
```

That should generate the URL to your action (clearing out the current ID) and then append the new route parameter.

Comment: No that doesn't work, that generates a URL of /Controller/Index/55/41
where 55 was the current index ID and 41 is the new selected ID

Comment: @CDSmith, sorry, you're right. It's using the current parameters. See update.

Comment: Nope still not right. It's weird tho. It generates the ID correctly but the URL generated is /Controller/41. For some reason it misses the action completely. I added a , null as a 4th param since URL.Action needs html attributes when a routedictionary is specified but that still gives the same thing... strange.

Comment: @CDSmith, No it doesn't. You're thinking of Html.ActionLink. Url.Action does not need a fourth parameter. Also, I've tested this and it should work fine. If there is an issue, ensure that your routing is not causing any issues.

Comment: you're right, that's what I was thinking of, removed 4th param and am still getting the same thing for some reason. /Controller/41 as newly selected ID. If I don't append a new ID and just reload the page using '@Url.Action("Index", "School")'; my url is /Controller/Index/55 which is the page I'm sitting on. If I add the new {id=""} param I only get /Contoller. The routing is correct otherwise I couldn't have gotten to the action in the first place with the passed in ID. I don't see any reason why you're example doesn't work tho, it should...

Comment: @CDSmith, Can you update your question with the exact code you're trying to use based off my answer? I'll give it another look. Also include any custom routing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't work much with .NeT  but something like this should work

```
        if( selected==someValue){   
        location.href= location.href+'?id=' + id;
        }
```

Comment: I'm trying to use jquery and convention over any hard coded text. @Brandon's example "should" work but doesn't but that's the correct way and the preferred direction in MVC with jquery

Comment: The current url that I'm sitting on is /Controller/Index/55 so if I append ?id=41 then I get /Controller/Index/55/41 which is an invalid route